# Bokeh dropdown - plot not able to be updated

Tags: python, function, histogram, dropdown, bokeh

I just start to use Bokeh making a dropdown menu following the document. 
I want to select the "country" I want to show it on the plot (Histogram). I can see the country from the dropdown menu now, but the "country" which I select does not add into the plot(Histogram) - this means that the plot is not able to be updated using the dropdown menu. I think something wrong with my "function to call". Since I'm quite new in Bokeh. I need advice and much appreciated.

```
    def function_to_call(attr, old, new):
        carriers_to_plot = [dropdown.labels[i] for i in dropdown.value]
        new_src = make_dataset(carriers_to_plot,
                               range_start = range_select.value[0],
                               range_end = range_select.value[1],
                               bin_width = binwidth_select.value)

        src.data.update(new_src.data)

    ### define dropdown widget
    menu = list(df['Country'].unique())
    dropdown = Dropdown(labels="Dropdown button", button_type="warning", menu=menu)
    dropdown.on_change('value', function_to_call)
    dropdown.on_click(function_to_call)


    #####make plot
    initial_carriers = [menu.labels[i] for i in menu.value]

    src = make_dataset(initial_carriers,
                      range_start = range_select.value[0],
                      range_end = range_select.value[1],
                      bin_width = binwidth_select.value)

    p = make_plot(src)
```

Comment: Are you actually running this as an application on the Bokeh server? Real Python callbacks can only function in Bokeh server applications. (The Bokeh server *is the Python process that runs the callback code*)  See: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was able to link it to the bokeh server.  here is my update code. Something must be missing because the plot not updated.

Comment: Please edit your question, it is impossible to decipher code in comments.

Comment: Thank you. I update the codes in the original post.

Comment: There's not really enough there to speculate. Have you run the simple examples in the repo? Or gone through the tutorial notebook chapter on server apps? A good way to learn is often to start with something known to work, and make small incremental changes towards what you actually want. Then if there is a problem. you can ask a focused question. Just diving in to a whole new thing and then asking "it doesn't work" is not really anything anyone can help with as there might ten things wrong. Would need a *complete* script to actually run personally in order to investigate or speculate.

Comment: Got it, thank you and check some examples